# how to get rid of kswapd0 process running in linux

Tags: linux

Frequently facing the issue of the kswapd0 running in one of the linux machines, what could be the reason for that, by looking more at the issue, understood that it will be because of the less memory, I tried the below options to avoid it:
echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
cat /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches

sudo cat /proc/sys/vm/swappiness
sudo sysctl vm.swappiness=60

but it does not yield fruitful results, what could be the best method to avoid it, or its something some action needs to be taken on the RAM memory of the machine, Any suggestions on this ?

Every time we observe , all the running apps are killed automatically and kswapd0 occupies the complete cpu and memory.

Comment: So you're running out of RAM, and you're asking what you can do to avoid this? Have you considered running fewer programs or installing more RAM?

Comment: You can make a cron job to periodically kill it.

Comment: @thatotherguy actually we considered those, but, its like some time i see even when we have enough memory, what could be the possible reasons for that?

Comment: @JoePerri  Doing same currently. But, do we have any other solution on that ?